# Xscreensaver loads over Brave Browser running videos

Tags: ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu over ARM (RPi4), and I have XScreenSaver installed.

The screensaver loads while Brave Browser plays Youtube videos, though. It doesn't load while VLC is running videos.

XScreenSaver's wiki says that Chromium browsers should handle this by themselves: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XScreenSaver

Does anyone know what I should do to change this behavior, blocking XScreenSaver to start when there's any media running?